# Oculus Quest & Unity: Hand Tracking: Grab Objects in different ways

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus, quest, oculusquest

I have made a simple game for my Oculus Quest with unity where the player has to sort different objects. The player grabs these objects with his hands. So I have used the hand-tracking. Therefore I followed the instructions of this [Tutorial Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UoSzhoZ18bE) and its added comments. And it works! :)

Now I wanted to add more difficulty: One object should only be grabbed by pinching thumb and index finger. One object only by pinching thumb and middle finger. One object by making a fist etc.
Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to make a "grab behavior" valid only for one certain object.

Thanks in advance

SchwarzbrotMitHummus